# Excel Loop through list,transpose and create a matrix based on cell content

Tags: vba, excel, transpose

I am receiving a large file 500k+ lines but all the content is in column A. I need to run a macro that will transpose the data into matrix form but will only create a new row when it finds `"KEY*"` in the ActiveCell. For example:

```
| KEY 4759839 | asljhk | 35049 | | sklahksdjf|
| KEY 359     | skj    | 487   |y| 2985789   |
```

The above data in my file would originally look like this in column A:

```
KEY 4759839
asljhk
35049

sklahksdjf
KEY 359
skj
487
y
2985789
```

Considerations:

- Blank cells need to be transposed as well, so the macro cant stop based on emptyCell
- The number of cells between KEY's is not constant so it actually needs to read the cell to know if it should create a new row
- It can either stop based on say 20 empty cells in a row or prompt for a max row number
- (Optional) It would be nice if there was some sort of visual indicator for the last item in a row so that its possible to tell if the last item(s) were blank cells

I searched around and found a macro that had the same general theme but it went based on every 6 lines and I did not know enough to try to modify it for my case. But in case it helps here it is:

```
Sub kTest()
    Dim a, w(), i As Long, j As Long, c As Integer
    a = Range([a1], [a500000].End(xlUp))
    ReDim w(1 To UBound(a, 1), 1 To 6)
    j = 1
    For i = 1 To UBound(a, 1)
        c = 1 + (i - 1) Mod 6: w(j, c) = a(i, 1)
        If c = 6 Then j = j + 1
    Next i
    [c1].Resize(j, 6) = w
End Sub
```

I would greatly appreciate any help you can give me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested and works:

```
    Sub test()
    Row = 0
    col = 1

    'Find the last not empty cell by selecting the bottom cell and moving up
    Max = Range("A650000").End(xlUp).Row 'Or whatever the last allowed row number is

    'loop through the data
    For i = 1 To Max
        'Check if the left 3 characters of the cell are "KEY" and start a new row if they are
        If (Left(Range("A" & i).Value, 3) = "KEY") Then
             Row = Row + 1
             col = 1
        End If

        Cells(Row, col).Value = Range("A" & i).Value
        If (i > Row) Then
            Range("A" & i).Value = ""
        End If
        col = col + 1

    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: It's fixed now. Tested and runs correctly even if the KEY values are not spaced constantly

Comment: For your optional requirement try this in the above code: If (Left(Range("A" & i).Value, 3) = "KEY") Then
             Cells(Row + 1, col) = "END"
             Row = Row + 1
             col = 1
        End If

Comment: Doing this over 500k records will take several minutes (actually around 7 minutes on my machine).

Comment: This worked perfectly the very first time although it takes quite awhile (that is not a very big deal). I will try your option bit now as well. Thanks!!

Comment: If the other method runs in a second compared to 7 minutes then I highly recommend trying to get @assylias's code to work for you!

Comment: @Dan Haha - if he only needs it once, and needs to spend more than 7 minutes on my solution to get it to work, then yours is better!

Comment: Also turn screen updating off for this code, that should speed it up.

Comment: I will actually be running it on a regular basis. Possibly daily but there are a million other things outside of Excel that I could be doing for that 7min if need be :)

Comment: @assylias Sure but it could be useful for others for the future

Comment: It looks like it was a typo and we got a happy ending ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This works with the sample data you provided in your question - it outputs the result in a table starting in B1. It runs in less than one second for 500k rows on my machine.

```
Sub kTest()
    Dim originalData As Variant
    Dim result As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim countKeys As Long
    Dim countColumns As Long
    Dim maxColumns As Long

    originalData = Range([a1], [a500000].End(xlUp))

    countKeys = 0
    maxColumns = 0

    'Calculate the number of lines and columns that will be required
    For i = LBound(originalData, 1) To UBound(originalData, 1)
        If Left(originalData(i, 1), 3) = "KEY" Then
            countKeys = countKeys + 1
            maxColumns = IIf(countColumns > maxColumns, countColumns, maxColumns)
            countColumns = 1
        Else
            countColumns = countColumns + 1
        End If
    Next i

    'Create the resulting array
    ReDim result(1 To countKeys, 1 To maxColumns) As Variant

    j = 0
    k = 1
    For i = LBound(originalData, 1) To UBound(originalData, 1)
        If Left(originalData(i, 1), 3) = "KEY" Then
            j = j + 1
            k = 1
        Else
            k = k + 1
        End If
        result(j, k) = originalData(i, 1)
    Next i

    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells(1, 2).Resize(UBound(result, 1), UBound(result, 2)) = result
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: How did you generate the test data? Would you mind testing my method on your test data to see it runs at a decent speed?

Comment: See my comment to your answer. I just copied the sample data a number of times to get to 500k rows.

Comment: When I tried this on my data is broke on this line `        result(j, k) = originalData(i, 1)`

Comment: @tehaaron what do you mean broke?

Comment: It might be a memory issue as this is using a lot of memory. One solution would be to do it in chunks.

Comment: @assylias Subscript out of Range

Comment: @tehaaron Not sure why without seeing your data - could happen if the first line of your file in not a KEYxxx

Comment: @assylias the very first value is and should always be "KEY " actually.

Comment: Are you interested in trying to get it to work or are you happy with the other solution? I can have another look if you want.

Comment: If you want to spend more time on it I would be happy to run any updates on my file and let you know if they work. Of course if it turns out to run faster I will use it! :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11116/discussion-between-assylias-and-tehaaron)